# Why doesn't /proc/self/fd/0 have a writable bit in serial session before a shell is started?

Tags: linux, busybox, file-descriptors, serial-console, write

I came across a program which uses a very old version of [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) library. All `write()` are done to `STDIN_FILENO`, like this:

```
write(STDIN_FILENO,prompt,plen)
```

`write` fails with -1 and `errno` set to `EBADF`. I wrote a C program which is started at the end of `/etc/init.d/rcS` which is in turn executed by `Busybox init` when system boots before interactive `sh` is started.  The C program lists `/proc/self/fd` directory, its output is:

```
l-wx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 2 -> /dev/console
l-wx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 1 -> /dev/console
lr-x------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 0 -> /dev/console
```

As you see 0 doesn't have `w` bit set and I think this is why `write` fails. However, after normal `sh` shell is started:

```
lrwx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 2 -> /dev/ttyS0
lrwx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 1 -> /dev/ttyS0
lrwx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 0 -> /dev/ttyS0
```

Now 0 has `w` set. Why does it happen?

Comment: The `EBADF` error is caused by an inexistent FD, not a permission error.  You're not looking precisely at the right place for the bug, and it appears to me that trying to use an input FD for output is a bug in itself, unless they reopen it.

Comment: `You're not looking precisely at the right place for the bug` - well, that may be right. Where should I look for an explanation of what's ging on? I think that it may be done by `Linux` serial console driver. `it appears to me that trying to use an input FD for output is a bug in itself, unless they reopen it.` - I wonder why writing to `stdin` works w/o problems in normal shell

Comment: This is a neat question, but please can you make more explicit what is meant by "before sh".  I'm interpreting this as if the linenoise program is run in-place of the normal init, or directly spawned by System V init.  However I had to make this assumption based on details of the command output; I don't think your description is entirely clear.

Comment: @sourcejedi: I added some explanation, I hope it's clearer now. Basically, yes, program that uses `linenoise` is started by `init`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can have multiple terminal devices.

Therefore `getty` is invoked with `ttyS0` specifically, as a parameter.  So it uses its own code to initialize all the FDs.  This happens to work differently to the kernel code which opens `/dev/console` for `init`.  One might guess `getty` opens the tty once with `O_RDWR`, then `dup`licates the FD.

I can see one obvious reason the [code](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/77835be2737305c395b0aa18728464b075673555/term-utils/agetty.c#L973) works this way.  `agetty` can also be invoked with `-` meaning stdin.  So always using `dup()` is the simplest implementation.

I'm not sure why that option was supported.  It is not necessarily used or supported in a standard System V `inittab`.  It seems to match the [older approach used under BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#Research_Unix-style.2FBSD-style), where `init` passes the terminal device as an open FD instead of a parameter  The older approach is for `init` to initialize all FDs ([link](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/s1/init.c), note only 2 FDs as `stderr` was added in the next version).

Since the question was edited to specify busybox, and cttyhack was mentioned, the obvious explanation in the case of busybox is "it keeps the code smaller".  This was also a driving feature of the historical unix code.

Comment: On `bysbox` there is a program called `cttyhack` that is used to respawn serial port, there is the following entry in `/etc/inittab`: `::respawn:/bin/cttyhack /bin/sh -l`. But the problem with 0 `fd` being unwritable also occurs on `Raspbian` system on `Raspberry Pi` which doesn't use `busybox`. Therefore I wonder whether `cttyhack` and `getty` use the same syscalls that make kernel setting up initial `fd`.

Comment: I was wrong - `cttyhack` is started after `rcS` is executed so the initial `fd` setup must be done wholly by the kernel itself.

Comment: Ask google: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=busybox+cttyhack+dup

Comment: Do you know where in the kernel source could I find initial serial tty implementation?

Comment: Yes, but it turns out it's not consistent with your results.  So my answer is wrong and I do not know what causes it.  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c?v=4.7#L1012

Comment: I checked what `stdin` does not have `w` only over serial connection - it does have `w` when serial is disabled.